# How to transformation Oracle TIMESTAMP?

Tags: oracle

I want to transformation Oracle TIMESTAMP to 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'

How to exchange TIMESTAMP ?

↓ This method is not good

```
SELECT 
TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS:FF') AS TIME_STAMP
FROM
ALL_OBJECTS
```

Please teach me your knowledge

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: A `TIMESTAMP` is a binary data-type consisting of 7-20 bytes (century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second then, optionally, up to 6 bytes for fractional seconds and, optionally, 7 bytes for time zone). It **ALWAYS** has the same binary components and it is **NEVER** stored in any particular human-readable format. Since it does not get stored with any format then it is **IMPOSSIBLE** to change how it is stored. What you are probably asking is how to **display** the date in a given format; which you want to use `TO_CHAR` when you query the column. But the question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Your query doesn't work because there's no `TIMESTAMP` column in `ALL_OBJECTS`. Even if there were such a column, you'd get - as result - *a lot* of rows. In my 21cXE, that would be

```
SQL> select count(*) from all_objects;

  COUNT(*)
----------
     64460
```

rows; what would you do with that?

---

Perhaps you meant to do this?

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS:FF') AS TIME_STAMP FROM dual;

TIME_STAMP
-----------------------------
2023-07-13 05:47:48:130000
```

---

Alternatively, you could alter session to avoid `TO_CHAR`, e.g.

```
SQL> select systimestamp from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
13-JUL-23 05.52.06.291000 AM +02:00

SQL> alter session set nls_timestamp_tz_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss:ff';

Session altered.

SQL> select systimestamp from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023-07-13 05:56:58:734000

SQL>
```

To check what are default values, see e.g.

```
SQL> select parameter, value from v$nls_parameters
  2  where parameter in ('NLS_DATE_FORMAT', 'NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT', 'NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT');

PARAMETER                      VALUE
------------------------------ ------------------------------
NLS_DATE_FORMAT                DD-MON-RR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT           dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff3
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT        yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss:ff

SQL>
```